# Setting isSelected to true not changing image

Tags: swift, uibutton, uikit

I have a tableview cell that has an image for a like button that is set like this,

```
            upArrow.setImage(UIImage(named: "likeButtonFill"), for: .selected)
            upArrow.setImage( UIImage(named: "likeButton"), for: .normal)
```

however, whenever I set

```
upArrow.isSelected = true
```

the image on the button never changes.

Comment: What difference does it make between .selected and .normal when it comes to `UIButton`?

Comment: @ElTomato Setting that determines the images that appears when the button property .isSelected is changed.

Comment: I did a really quick test in playgrounds ([gist](https://gist.github.com/RustyKnight/d4e62e210c2a950abc99a4d143ee96be), bring own images) and it seems to work okay for me

Comment: How do you know that your button is not initially selected?

Comment: make sure you selected image is not `nil`: `UIImage(named: "likeButtonFill")!`